# Hide Object Keep Ambient Occlusion

Tags: shaders, transparency, shadows, ambient-occlusion

I need to hide an object but keep it's shadow and ambient occlusion effect. I am able to hide the object by assigning a transparent shader with Blend Mode: Alpha Blend and Shadow Blend Mode: Opaque. However, when the transparent material is applied the object's ambient occlusion effect disappears. Is there a way to also keep the object's ambient occlusion effect while hiding the object itself in Eevee?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try this one. This only works in Cycles.
[image]
[image]